# php: strtotime("12/31/2004 +6 month")); not returning the last day of June

Tags: php, strtotime

I expected this functional to return `6/30/2005` instead of `7/1/2005`.

```
print date("m/d/Y", strtotime("12/31/2004 +6 month"));
```

Similarly, `print date("m/d/Y", strtotime("1/31/2011 +1 month"))` returns `03/03/2011` while would like it to return `2/28/2011`.

Does anyone know if there is a straight forward way to show the last day of the added month?

Comment: `strtotime` works with European style dates, if I remember correctly. try `31/1/2011` etc.

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime("last day of 12/31/2004 + 6 month")); // 6/30/2005
echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime("last day of 1/31/2011 + 1 month")); // 2/28/2011
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kfki85)

**Edit:** For your reference, here is a link to the [documentation for relative times](http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Answer (score 2):

as strtotime continue in to next month if there isn't enoghe days that month,
you can back 6 month and check if its end up on the start date

```
  $date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$date} +6 months"));
  $date3 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$date2} -6 months"));
  if($date3 != $date)
  {
     $date2 = date("Y-m-t", strtotime("{$date2} -1 months"));
  }
```

(or in your case "m/t/Y")

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to actually go one month ahead of the day you want and then make the **day** value zero. Also, mktime() might be easier

```
$mymonth = 2;   // I want the last day of February
echo date('m/d/Y', mktime(0,0,0,$mymonth+1,0,2011));
```

This should return 2/28/2011.

Answer (score 0):

strtotime does the best it can with conflicting information. Saying

```
1/31/2011 +1month
```

would mean advancing to

```
2/31/2011
```

but February only has 28 (sometimes 29) days. 2011 isn't a leap year, so the "31st of February" gets normalized to "March 3rd".

The same applies for '12/31/2004 +6month'. That takes you to June 31st, 2005. But June only has 30 days, so the date is normalized to July 1st instead.